# How to pass params from Route (react-router-dom) to render function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

Is possible to do something like this:

```
<Route exact path="/activate/:token" render={this.activateAccount} />
```

then in same component

```
activateAccount(token) {
    console.log(token);
    return null;
}
```

How to pass token?

Is my logic correct? Learning MERN a bit, what I find confusing right now is how to move between backend and frontend, for example here when I generate activate account URL I have something like

```
http://localhost:5006/api/activate/8d7f5b25befb70045b5cb36893fa0f7688b85504
```

Now my NodeJS/Express is running on 5006 port and my ReactJS is on 3006, not sure what is logic here, I can finish everything on my NodeJS side in this case but not sure how to redirect later on to /login/ on frontend.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter of `activateAccount` won't be `token`:

```
<Route exact path="/activate/:token" render={this.activateAccount} />
```

As [the reference](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) states, `Route` `render` function receives [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props):

> All three render methods will be passed the same three route props
>
> - match
> - location
> - history

Otherwise it wouldn't be impossible to make use of them in route component.

It is:

```
activateAccount(props) {
    console.log(props.match.token);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for point in right direction! This worked just fine, activateAccount({ match }) { console.log(match.params.token); return null;}